# Get Top 3 Records By Date By Day SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I have table with rows that look like this:

```
DateTime, Field1, Field2, Field3
```

I want to get the TOP 3 records by date, by day. For one record I would execute

```
SELECT TOP(3) * 
FROM tum
```

I need that for each day. I am assuming I would use partition or cross apply, but the actual syntax for this is not clear to me.

Comment: `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition convert(date, datetime) order by ?) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: This syntax does not seem correct.  row_number takes 0 arguments.

Comment: @JeremyReynolds . . . Huh?  There are no arguments.